# Bypass lazy variable evaluation in Xalan XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

I am working on a XSLT that we are using to processes an XML file, and I need to trigger some action if an element is there.  Created a Java Extension thinking I could simply set a variable it would evaluate like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//attachments/attachment" xmlns:fbattach="java://com.package.ProcessAttachment">
    <xsl:variable name="content"><xsl:value-of select="filedata" /></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="fileName"><xsl:value-of select="name"  /></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="fileType"><xsl:value-of select="fileType" /></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="attachmentId"><xsl:value-of select="fbattach:test($fileName, $fileType, $content)" /></xsl:variable>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem I am seeing is that `attachmentId` doesn't seem to get evaluated unless I do something like this:

```
<attatchment2><xsl:value-of select="$attachmentId" /></attatchment2>
```

It seems that Xalan is lazily-evaluating the variables, only doing the evaluation when it is being used for output.  [This](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xpath/operations/Variable.html#execute(org.apache.xpath.XPathContext,%20boolean)) and [this](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xpath/VariableStack.html#getLocalVariable(org.apache.xpath.XPathContext,%20int,%20boolean)) seem to corroborate this theory.

Is there a way to force the evaluation, like a setting or something?

Comment: If it isn't needed/used, why do you want it to execute? You could try forcing/tricking it into executing by making the call and selecting something that won't exist, like using it in a predicate filter for the parent of the root node in a value-of: `<xsl:value-of select="/..[. = $attachemntId]"/>`

Comment: Another option might be `xsl:message` outputting it.

Comment: @MadsHansen In this case I don't want it to be part of the output per say, but I need to trigger an action when these particular tags occur in the original file.  I am trying to do it as one fell swoop in the XSLT, but another option I have considered would be to use XPATH on the original document to pull out the attachments and do the necessary work.  Basically I am trying to avoid having to write code in 2 places and just have it all "work" from the XSLT transformation.

Comment: Makes sense. Variables may be lazily evaluated, so using it in an XPath that attempts to fetch a value (but is guaranteed not to produce anything) may be one way, or use inside of an `xsl:comment`, or as @Martin Honnen suggests, use `xsl:message` to force the processor to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Your solution worked beautifully!  If you want to present it as an answer I can accept it to give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that an expression is evaluated one way is to use it inside of `xsl:message` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#message).